# selenium grid 2 MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

my test environment is : ubuntu 12.04, firefox 31.0, selenium 2.42.2

my test case is : open a web page, click a button to open a popup window, double click one row of this popup window.

there was error occurred in 'double click one row of this popup window' :

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException : Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0): [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLTableRowElement]] Command duration or timeout: 29 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=31.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]  Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=ae674cc9-7944-4e86-a893-7792cdd121ce, version=31.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

my code is :

```
    @Parameters({"browser","os","dataKey","username","workstation","browserVersion"})
        @Test
        public void intSelenium(String browser, String os, String dataKey, String username, String workstation, @Optional String browserVersion)
                throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

            DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capability.setBrowserName(browser); 
            if(os.equals("LINUX")) {
                capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
            } else if(os.equals("WINDOWS")) {
                capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            }       

            if(browserVersion != null) {
                capability.setVersion(browserVersion);
            }
            testCasesData=map2.get(dataKey);

            try {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
                            driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                action = new Actions(driver);                       
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

            @Parameters({"dataKey"})
            @Test(alwaysRun=true,dependsOnMethods="intSelenium")
            public void Login (String dataKey){

                String value=null;
                String attName = null;

                driver.get("http://192.168.18.141:8080"+getValue("Login", "appUrl", true, dataKey));
                logger.info("Completed Login");
            }

            @Parameters({"dataKey"})
            @Test(alwaysRun=true,dependsOnMethods="Login")
            public void RegressionTest312 (String dataKey){

                String value=null;
                String attName = null;

                //double click to open specific page on right panel
                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='newBookingTreeBranch']//span[text()='Default Template']");
                element = driver.findElement(by);
                element.sendKeys("");       
                action.doubleClick(element).perform();

        // click twice to make the page editable, that is user/selenium can input values
                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='DefBookingBasicTO']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]");
                action.click(driver.findElement(by)).perform();
                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='DefBookingBasicTO']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]");
                action.click(driver.findElement(by)).perform();         

//click the input box, then input value in it
                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='DefBookingBasicTO']/div[3]/table/tbody//tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]//td[@fieldname='finalDest']//input[@type='text']");
                action.click(driver.findElement(by)).perform();

                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='DefBookingBasicTO']/div[3]/table/tbody//tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]//td[@fieldname='finalDest']//input[@type='text']");
                driver.findElement(by).sendKeys(getValue("RegressionTest312", "DefBookingInfo_FinalDest_input", true, dataKey));


                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='DefBookingBasicTO']/div[3]/table/tbody//tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]//td[@fieldname='finalDest']//input[@type='text']");
                driver.findElement(by).sendKeys(getValue("RegressionTest312", "DefBookingInfo_FinalDest_input", true, dataKey));

//click the button to open popup window, this popup window shows the search result according to the value input above
                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='DefBookingBasicTO']/div[3]/table/tbody//tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]//td[@fieldname='finalDest']//input[@type='button']");
                action.click(driver.findElement(by)).perform();

// select one row in popup window, and then double click to select this row data   
                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='LookupResultListTO']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]");
                action.click(driver.findElement(by)).perform();

                by = By.xpath("//div[@id='LookupResultListTO']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'none') or contains(@class,'hide'))][1]");
                element = driver.findElement(by);
                element.sendKeys("");       
                action.doubleClick(element).perform();


            }
```

how to solve this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: can u paste ur code...

Comment: Thanks @Anuragh27crony, I have pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

For clicking this button, when i change step to following, then this error disappear :

```
element = driver.findElement(by);
element.sendKeys("");       
element.click();
```

Also, don't forget :

```
capability.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
```